# Get card information and all post data in order sales before observer in magento 2

Tags: payment, checkout, magento-2.0

I have created a custom observer "sales_order_save_before". The event is working fine but when I tried to log the post data it always blank array. Although I can see the post data in console.I have used following code.

```
namespace Test\Check\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
class SalesOrderBeforeSaveObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
   public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
   {
        $this->_request = $request;
   }

   public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
   {
      $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
      if ($order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode() == 'test') 
    {
        $data=$this->_request;
        print_r($data);die; /*Not working */ 
    }
    return $this;
  } }
```

Comment: I need to get the credit cart information which is displaying as source parameter in console

Comment: I also need card information... for that i need a observer which can be called before https://api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com/merchants/swgx85nh2d5c4kjs/client_api/v1/payment_methods/credit_cards request by the payment gateway. Can anyone help? Need to know which observer to be use...